# How to interpret the relation or interaction between two variables or features in general for classification?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, feature-selection

Suppose I have several features like $X_1, X_2, X_3$ etc. In my model, I have to know whether $X_1$ and $X_2$ will have an impact together. I read somewhere we can make a new feature by $( X_1*X_2 )$, which will have a new coefficient, lets say $C$. My question is, in R, for regression we can use a default function to combine two variables? But, what's happening inside that function? Are they doing $X_1*X_2$ or $X_1+X_2$? In python sklearn, as of my knowledge there is no way of doing that.

So, please would someone help me and explain the relevance of combining two features theoretically and practically?

Answer (score 2):

What you are talking about are basic inteaction effets. You could think forexample of simple  model:

`y = a + b1*x1 + b2*x2 + e`

If we add and interaction-term  to  the   model  depicted, the following term consequences.

`y = a + b1*x1 + b2*x2 + b3*x1*x2 + e`

By simply reordering, we find

`y = (a + b1*x1) + x2*(b2+b3*x1) + e`

The first parenthesis depicts the intercept and the second the regression’s slope. However, both elements are subject to  the  level of x1. Despite  term appearing rather  econometrically  tame,  Braumöller  (2004) shows that interpreting models with multiplicative terms often goes askew especially when turning to the lower-order coefficients `b1` and `b2`.

The regression’s slope will equal `b1` only if `x2` equals zero. Thus `b1`
denotes  the  simple  effect  of `x1` on `y`. Similar, `x2` denotes the simple effect on `y` since `y = a + b2*x2 + e ; for x1=0`. Similarly, `a` is the intercept when both `x1` an`x2` are zero.

`b3` finally depicts the interactions between `x1`and `x2`. And here lies the crux: 
First, you can only interpret `x3`if you incorporate both `x1`and `x2`in your regression. For a detailed analysis of this matter see Whisman, Mark A., and Gary H. McClelland. "Designing, testing, and interpreting interactions and moderator effects in family research." Journal of Family Psychology 19.1 (2005): 111. Second, you need "meaniful" values for `x1=0`and `x2=0`. One idea might be a centering at meaningful values or at means. For a more detailed discussion of this matter check here: [When conducting multiple regression, when should you center your predictor variables & when should you standardize them?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29781/when-should-you-center-your-data-when-should-you-standardize)

Statistic packages like Stata and R usually do everything for you. Practically, you can incorporate x1, x2 and a third variable x1*x2. But usually it is better to merely incorporate x1 and x2 and "tell" R/Stata to gauge an interactio effect too ( x1##x2 or x1#x2 in Stata). R is a little different. Check here: [Different ways to write interaction terms in lm?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19271/different-ways-to-write-interaction-terms-in-lm)

Comment: So helpful . I will read the links. So, the effect of above mentioned things will remain the same or atleast having same interpretation in classification also.

Comment: That is true - but only if you leave x1 and x2 in the regression when adding the interaction. Only having the interaction without x1 and x2 leads to false interpretation . If the above answers your question, try to indicate so via the button :)

Comment: Sleep - Actually, i didn't understand the last comment ? Can you please be specific when you are free .

Comment: Sure, no problem. I merely wanted to point out that you need to include both the individual effects and the interaction term if you want to be able to have meaningfull interpretations. If you were to add an interaction and not the individual effects, a meaningful interpretation is hard (or even impossible). That is why packages like Stata/R/SAS and alike allow a notation that includes the individual and the interaction in on step. For Stata you might use x1##x2. this results in x1, x2 and x1*x2 in one step.

Comment: My pleasure! Also, if you categorical data, make sure you think about how to code it (e.g. dummy 0/1 vs effect -1/1 and alike).

Comment: Sleeps - Exactly i am doing the same.As, i am having more text features , I am converting categorical values to dummy variables with 0 and 1.

Comment: Cool! Check West, Stephen G., Leona S. Aiken, and Jennifer L. Krull. "Experimental personality designs: Analyzing categorical by continuous variable interactions." Journal of personality 64 (1996): 1-48. for a nice overview on what to consider when coding interactions with categorical data.

Comment: will definitely have a look

Comment: @sarathRNair please mark questions as answered.

Comment: @SarathRNair please mark the question as answered. It is more easy to find for others.